# Rails, link_to is using a period and not a / in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= link_to 'View the item', items_url(@item, :only_path => false) %>
```

Which is generating:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/items.124/
```

This is no good as it has a period where it should have a forward slash like:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/items/124/
```

Anyone know y? thanks

Comment: please post your routes file because the error is probably in there :)

Answer (score 15):

shoot, should be `item_url` not `items_url`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my `form_for` generated URL.  I had accidentally put `resource my_resource` instead of `resources my_resources`.

Answer (score 0):

using `Rails 7.0.5` at time of response. @Damith is correct, the path helper needs to be singular and not plural.

This response is meant to illuminate a skosh.
The plurality in Rails helper paths point to page indexes, or collection of objects, whereas the single object reference in the path helper, identifies it as a reference for a single object, typically used in conjunction with a `#show` action in a controller.
When you used the plural version `items_url` with more objects than expected, Rails treats the additional argument as a format specifier because the route definition is not expecting an ID for a nested resource.

Using the singular version `item_url` correctly indicates to Rails that you're looking for a nested route that includes an ID attribute on your model, hence fixing the malformed URI. It's a subtle but important distinction in Rails path helpers.